# How can I make my model to overfit to my data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I use Acrobot-v1 of openai gym to make my model
The observation state size is 6 and action is -1 or 1 or 0. 
I want to check whether my model is capable of learning.

So, I used cross-validation method and my set is divided to training set of 64000 state-action pair and validation set of 16000 state-action pair.

But whenever I increase the number of neurons in my hidden layer, validation loss keep decreasing in training process. 
I've learned many parameter makes overfitting and the overfitting can be detected by watching increase of validation loss.
I do not know what should I do.

```
self.DEncoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nfeature),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()
])

self.DDecoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nInHidden),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.nState*self.npred),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((self.npred,self.nState,1))
])
```

This is my model. I have used l2 loss (mse, mean squared error).

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your validation set is a subset of your training set.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're asking, mainly because you **never** want your model to overfit.

Overfitting occurs when the **validation loss** increases while **train loss** keeps decreasing, which means your model will only work with the training set data and not with the rest of the data as intended. If your validation loss keeps decreasing your model may just need more training epochs to achieve an optimal performance.

Also separating part of the Train set as Validation set is called **Hold-out Validation**, not Cross-Validation.

Comment: Sorry due to my poor explanation and thank you for your help.

Comment: My question is that even if the number of parameters is quite large considering size of state, why loss of validation set is not increasing.

Comment: Oh well, increasing the number of parameters does not always imply overfitting, for example your model could be **underfitting** due to the lack of parameters and in that case adding more neurons helps your model to better fit the data. There are also several other hyper-parameters besides number of neurons that can affect under/overfitting.